# How do I add a Label over a ListBox in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, label

I have currently a `ListBox` in a `DockPanel` (that represents a wonderful Diaballik game) and at the end I want to be able to show up a label *Victory* over the grid made by the boxes like in the picture :

[image]

```
<DockPanel>
    <ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Cases}"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCase, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">

        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding Size}"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid >
                    <Ellipse Fill="{Binding Color}" Width="50" Height="50" Visibility="{Binding HasPawn, Converter={StaticResource bool2visibility}}"/>                        
                    ...
                 </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <Label Content="VICTORY" />  <!-- How can this go over the list box ?  -->
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this (the behaviour of a `Grid` is such that it will just "stack" the items "on top" of each other):

```
<DockPanel>
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Cases}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCase, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">

            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding Size}"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid >
                        <Ellipse Fill="{Binding Color}" Width="50" Height="50" Visibility="{Binding HasPawn, Converter={StaticResource bool2visibility}}"/>                        
                        ...
                     </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

        <Label Content="VICTORY" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />  <!-- How can this go over the list box ?  -->
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```